# Convert data from User-defined table type to XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, user-defined-types

I have user-defined table type:

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[t_data] AS TABLE(
      [nID] [numeric](20, 0) NOT NULL,
      [nLocationKey] [numeric](20, 0) NULL,
      [nMTkey] [numeric](20, 0) NULL
    )
```

Need to get XML like:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LISTSAVE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
       <LIST>
            <ITEM>
                 <NMTKEY>1231</NMTKEY>
                 <NLOCATIONKEY>1123</NLOCATIONKEY>
            </ITEM>
            <ITEM>
                 <NMTKEY>7778</NMTKEY>
                 <NLOCATIONKEY>9999</NLOCATIONKEY>
            </ITEM>
       </LIST>
  </LISTSAVE>
```

I want to make function that will make xml from this data like:

```
   CREATE FUNCTION [LOC_API].[wrapLocationData] (
       @in_oData dbo.t_data READONLY
       )
       RETURNS XML
       AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @l_cData XML
    /* Data to XML conversion */
    RETURN @l_cData
    END
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573297/sql-to-generate-xml-of-table-data

Comment: It is for table. I need for table type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML query is no different because you use a table type.

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[wrapLocationData]
(
  @in_oData dbo.t_data READONLY
) RETURNS XML AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @l_cData XML;

  WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
                     'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
  SELECT @l_cData = (
                    SELECT (
                           SELECT D.nMTkey AS NMTKEY,
                                  D.nLocationKey AS NLOCATIONKEY
                           FROM @in_oData AS D
                           FOR XML PATH('ITEM'), ROOT('LIST'), TYPE
                           )
                    FOR XML PATH('LISTSAVE'), TYPE
                    );

  RETURN @l_cData;
END
```

Result:

```xml
<LISTSAVE xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <LIST xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <ITEM>
      <NMTKEY>3</NMTKEY>
      <NLOCATIONKEY>2</NLOCATIONKEY>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
      <NMTKEY>6</NMTKEY>
      <NLOCATIONKEY>5</NLOCATIONKEY>
    </ITEM>
  </LIST>
</LISTSAVE>
```

There is to my knowledge no sane way to avoid the double namespace declarations. See [How to remove xmlns from child elements with FOR XML](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23624/how-to-remove-xmlns-from-child-elements-with-for-xml)